# compute term vector without indexing in lucene 4

Tags: lucene, indexing

I am migrating my code from Lucene 3.5 to Lucene 4.1 but I am having some problems with getting the term vector without indexing.

The problem is, given a text string and an `Analyzer`, I need to compute the term vector (technically, find the terms and their frequencies tf). Obviously, it can be achieved by writing the index (using `IndexWriter`) and then reading them back (using `IndexReader`) but I reckon it would be expensive. Furthermore, I don't need document frequency (df). Thus, I think an indexing-free solution is suitable.

In Lucene 2 and 3, a simple technique for the above purpose is to use `QueryTermVector` which extends `TermFreqVector` and has a constructor taking a string and an Analyzer. Unfortunately, `QueryTermVector` (along with `TermFreqVector`) has been removed in Lucene 4 and it seems the migration documentation did not mention anything about `QueryTermVector`.

Do you have a solution for this problem in Lucene 4? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to know the terms/frequencies, you can just obtain the single tokens directly from the analyzer (you can get the TF by counting them, e.g. by using a Map or a Multiset).

This is how you do it in Lucene 4.0:

```
TokenStream ts = analyzer.tokenStream(field, new StringReader(text));
CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = ts.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);


while (ts.incrementToken()) {
    String term = charTermAttribute.toString();
    //term contains your token
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Just hope Lucene 4 offers an alternative to `QueryTermVector`. I guess not :(